# How to show precentage in Seaborn countplot

Tags: pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm tring to plot distribution of some column by other column (both categoricals).
In this example, I want to plot the ditribution of sexual orientation by city in California:
My data contains profiles of people from OkCupid app.

I've tried the following countplot:

```py
sns.countplot(x='city',data=df_big_cities, hue='orientation')
```

And here what I've got:

[image]

But I want to add the precentage of every orientation for **each city** (each city should sums up to 100%).
There's any cool way to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: You want percentage instead of count?

Comment: Yes please! I saw some answers but all of them was about only 2 bars or for global percentage , not local (for each city)